# What's the meaning of this nice Probability statement/reply?

Tags: probability

I've come up with this statement/reply for when someone asks you how you think you would fare in a question with 2 options (mostly in a situation where the questions have some repetitive part, such as, is a chord major or minor,etc.) :

"I'm 50% sure that I'll get it right more times than not"

I want to use it in situations where I don't know the answer, but I wanted to confirm whether this statement is the same as saying

"there is a 50% chance of getting each individual question right"

Suggestions are welcome

Comment: No it is not the same. The first statement means, if I repeated the experiment some non-trivial number of times, the probability of getting more than half right is at least $50\%$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpret "50% sure/chance" as a probability p = 0.5.

The first case says p = 0.5 that the event $n_s > n_f$ (number of successes > number of failures) occurs. This in turn means the probability of success $p_s > 0.5$.

In the second case you are saying $p_s=0.5$.